Docker behaviour different on command line versus interactive prompt
I have a Docker image that fails to find Perl dependencies when run from the command line, but runs fine if I execute the same command from an interactive prompt in the Docker image.
I am running this image as follows from the command line:

docker run --rm -v /srv/data:/srv/data wgs_binning -i
/srv/data/contigs.fna.gz -c /srv/data/coverage.tsv -o
/srv/data/test_binning

This results in the following issue related to Perl dependencies:

Can't locate LWP/Simple.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
LWP::Simple module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.36.0
/usr/local/share/perl/5.36.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.36
/usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.36 /usr/share/perl/5.36
/usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /opt/conda/bin/run_MaxBin.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/conda/bin/run_MaxBin.pl line
4.

I am accessing an interactive prompt of the Docker image with:

docker run --rm -it -v /srv/data:/srv/data --entrypoint bash
wgs_binning

If I run the following in the interactive prompt, it runs without issue:

python3 binning -i /srv/data/contigs.fna.gz -c /srv/data/coverage.tsv
-o /srv/data/test_binning

The entry point of my Dockerfile is ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "binning"] so I would have expected the behaviour in these two situations to be identical.
Is there some sort of pathing or permission difference between running a command on the command line versus on an interactive prompt?
The offending program here is called MaxBin and this is install in the Dockerfile via mamba. Not sure this should matter, but perhaps there is an interaction between the conda/mamba environment that differs under the two scenarios I outlined?
Thanks,
Donovan
Full Dockerfile as as follows:
FROM python:3.12.4-slim-bookworm

LABEL description="Recover MAGs from assembled contigs using UniteM."
LABEL maintainer="Donovan Parks <donovan@koonkie.com>"
LABEL version="0.1.0"

# install additional Linux dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y -m && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
    wget && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install Mambaforge
RUN wget --quiet https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Mambaforge-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/mambaforge.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/mambaforge.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/mambaforge.sh

# Put mamba in path so we can use mamba commands
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/conda/bin"

# initialize shell with conda
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda init bash

# install bioinformatics tools with mamba where available
RUN mamba install -c bioconda \
    metabat2=2.15 \
    maxbin2=2.2.7 \
    && mamba clean --all

# activate the virtual environment and install dependencies
WORKDIR /wgs_pipeline/dependencies
RUN /opt/conda/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
COPY KBL/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN /opt/conda/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt unitem==1.2.6 checkm-genome==1.2.3

# install KBL and WPL libraries
WORKDIR /wgs_pipeline/libraries
COPY wgs_pipeline/wgs_pipeline/wpl/*.py ./wpl/
COPY KBL/kbl/*.py ./kbl/
COPY KBL/kbl/external/*.py ./kbl/external/

# add KBL and WPL libraries to Python path
ENV PYTHONPATH="/wgs_pipeline"
ENV PYTHONPATH="/wgs_pipeline/libraries:${PYTHONPATH}"

# copy WGS application script(s)
WORKDIR /wgs_pipeline/apps
COPY wgs_pipeline/wgs_pipeline/apps/binning/*.py ./binning/
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "binning"]


Whether bash or another shell is running at all can sometimes make a difference.  The ENTRYPOINT-based setup won't run a shell at all, but starting an interactive shell can do things like read dotfiles that can change environment variables.  Almost everything you show in the question is Python-related, except that the error message is about Perl; what part of this setup uses Perl?

can you try with docker run --rm --entrypoint "python" -v /srv/data:/srv/data wgs_binning -c "binning -i /srv/data/contigs.fna.gz -c /srv/data/coverage.tsv -o /srv/data/test_binning"?

The "problem" program here is MaxBin which is a Perl program with lots of Perl dependencies.

Hi @ha36d, running docker run --rm --entrypoint "python" -v /srv/data:/srv/data wgs_binning -c "binning -i /srv/data/contigs.fna.gz -c /srv/data/coverage.tsv -o /srv/data/test_binning" results in the error NameError: name 'binning' is not defined.

Hi @DavidMaze, is there a way to set the ENTRYPOINT so it will execute the bash shell and then run the Python script? Perhaps the bash shell needs to run to properly setup the Perl dependencies? The following still fails to identify the Perl dependencies: docker run --rm -v /srv/data:/srv/data wgs_binning /bin/bash -c "python3 binning -i /srv/data/contigs.fna.gz -c /srv/data/coverage.tsv -o /srv/data/test_binning"

In principle you could set something like ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "binning \"$@\"", "binning"], but that gets complicated and it seems like it's more working around a missing setting than really addressing the problem.

Look at the environment variables in both cases (maybe just running perl -V). I bet the working case has settings for PERL5LIB and the non-working case doesn't. As someone already noted, an interactive session uses various dot files that may be setting environment variables that impact this.
And, you can pass environment variables to the process inside docker with --env or --env-file.

Thanks for this. This isn't the issue per se. The issue is that I am installing software via Conda. When I enter the Docker image interactively it activates the base Conda environment which has a different version of Perl installed. So, now I'm just trying to determine how to active the base Conda environment when running a command externally.

The solution for my specific case was to change the ENTRYPOINT to ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "base", "python3", "binning"]
